# Десериализация json и перевод в LIST

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, unity3d-android

Кто может подсказать как десериализовать данный json в юнити и желательно перевести его в List, ранее работал с json где 1 объект, а тут их много и что-то мне подсказывает что тут нужен Dictionary

Мой мозг дошёл до такого:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class CurrencyValue
{
    public string code;
    public string alphaCode;
    public string numericCode;
    public string name;
    public int rate;
    public string date;
    public int inverseRate;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class ValueList
{
    public List<CurrencyValue> = new List<CurrencyValue>(); 
}
```

Но я абсолютно не понимаю, как вывести данные из json такого формата в этот лист

```
    {
        "eur": {
            "code": "EUR",
            "alphaCode": "EUR",
            "numericCode": "978",
            "name": "Euro",
            "rate": 0.9432588195335,
            "date": "Wed, 4 Jan 2023 11:55:01 GMT",
            "inverseRate": 1.0601544128626
        },
        "gbp": {
            "code": "GBP",
            "alphaCode": "GBP",
            "numericCode": "826",
            "name": "U.K. Pound Sterling",
            "rate": 0.83020895749074,
            "date": "Wed, 4 Jan 2023 11:55:01 GMT",
            "inverseRate": 1.2045160329545
        },
        "jpy": {
            "code": "JPY",
            "alphaCode": "JPY",
            "numericCode": "392",
            "name": "Japanese Yen",
            "rate": 130.50885010342,
            "date": "Wed, 4 Jan 2023 11:55:01 GMT",
            "inverseRate": 0.0076623156146695
        }
    }
```

Comment: Так вроде в Unity уже newtonsoft.json завезли: [Serialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializedictionary.htm) и [Deserialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm). Если по-простому, можно словарь сначала создать, а потом перебрать его значения в foreach и засунуть их в список.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем всё оказалось проще чем думалось, спасибо @Qwer за подсказку.
Теперь код выглядит так, кому нужно.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
       public TextAsset json; //cюда физически пихаем jsonFile
       private Dictionary<string,CurrencyValue> JsonValues;
       string currency = "";
       decimal rate = 0;

       void Start()
       {
            JsonValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, 
            CurrencyValue>>(json.text);
       }
       //забираем любое значение из словаря по ключу
       void GetValue(string currencyIn)
       {
       Dictionary<string,CurrencyValue> JV  = JsonValues;
       foreach(var n in JV)
       {
           if(n.Key == currencyIn)
           {
           currency = n.Key;
           rate = n.Value.rate;
           }
       }
       }


       
}
    [System.Serializable]
    public class CurrencyValue
    {
        public string code;
        public string alphaCode;
        public string numericCode;
        public string name;
        public decimal rate;
        public string date;
        public decimal inverseRate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, CurrencyValue> ValueDictionary = new Dictionary<string, CurrencyValue>();
```

И нужно сменить тип с int на decimal `public decimal inverseRate;`